# VBA - How can I stop button resizing to cell size?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I use VBA to create my EDIT-buttons and see that its size changes depending on the cell size. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is how my code looks:

```
Dim t As Range
Dim btn As Button
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & fileCounter + 1)
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left + 2, t.Top + 2, t.Width - 2, t.Height - 2)
With btn
    .OnAction = "'EditInNotepad """ & strFilePath & """'"
    .Caption = "Edit"
    .name = ""
End With
```

[image]

Comment: change the values in `buttons.add`

Comment: @Warcupine Any examples? No matter what values i change, the button sizes still differ

Comment: Use hard-coded values for the last two parameters, which are width and height. Or may be just the last one if you want just a fixed height.

Comment: You also need to set the properties - move but don't size with cells  `.Placement = xlMove`